# How do I dynamically insert tags in a jade file output using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm making a small node.js express app with user logins. If user A connect, the page should show a button. If user B connect, the button shouldn't be there.

I tried the following

```
#{hideOrNot}
```

Where hideOrNot is a variable in my js app that has the value

```
'button(type="submit")'
```

if A connects but simply '' if B connects.

I guess it doesn't quite work that way in jade since it printed the text of the button tag instead of the actual button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `hideOrNot` a boolean (I'd suggest you call it `showButton` for example), and add the button in a simple if (since jade supports [JavaScript inline code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/))

```
- if(showButton)
    button(type="submit")
```